# Keycloak behind proxy fails to load static files in Firefox, producing multiple redirects and 403 error

Tags: nginx, firefox, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have some big `SPA` application. Previously, I secured this app with my custom (and I believe insecure) solution, based on `JWT` tokens. Now I've switched to using `Keycloak`. So, what I've done so far is deployed `Keycloak` service, configured `realms` and `clients` and also configured `nginx`. Indeed, there is too much configuration and code behind all this and it can not be minified to reproduce the problem (at least I tried to create some minified and reproducible example, but unfortunatelly it just works good - everything just works as expected). My `SPA` application is running inside `Docker` container and in `nginx` I'm using `upstreams` and `proxy_pass` directive. At this moment, when I go to my `SPA` for the first time I get redirected to `Keycloak` login page (good!), I enter my login and password and get redirected back to my `SPA`.

The problem is that in different browsers, I get different results at this last step. For example, in Chrome everything works good. while in Firefox I get a ton of `302` statuses for static files and each of these static files is returned with `Location` header pointing to `Keycloak`:

```
realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?redirect_uri=https://localhost/redirect_uri&response_type=code&scope=openid email profile&client_id=myclient&nonce=1d1869bb20ff43596ac98a01ea723c7e&state=3b667a82f9b962342a0415c97252c460
```

And I see literally hundreds redirects to this `auth` endpoint (just for each static file returned with `302` status code). I know there may be some problem with gzipped files, so I switched gzipping off.

So, why does `Keycloak` behave different in different browsers and what may be specific about Mozilla Firefox browser that it is unable to load static files? (PS. if I totally switch off keycloak, everything is getting loaded just fine).